# Holder for an Adapter

Tags: android, gridview, android-custom-view

I have a gridView in which I am populating a data using a custom Adapter. For that I have overridden the getView() method. However, as my gridView is a custom one, I had to use a static holder class(as seen in many examples provided online). If I do not wish to use the holder what other way can I implement it in? And why are getTag() and setTag() used? I searched about them but couldn't find sufficient explanation.

The Holder Class -

```
static class RecordHolder{
    ImageView imgView;
    TextView txtView;
}
```

The getView method -

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    RecordHolder holder = new RecordHolder();
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (getActivity()).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_line, parent, false);

        holder.imgView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        holder.txtView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (RecordHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    ResolveInfo resolveInfo = mAppList.get(position);
    holder.imgView.setImageDrawable(resolveInfo.loadIcon(getActivity().getPackageManager()));
    holder.txtView.setText(resolveInfo.loadLabel(getActivity().getPackageManager()));

    return row;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use

```
final ImageView imgView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
final TextView txtView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

But better to use **ViewHolder**

A ViewHolder object stores each of the component views inside the tag field of the Layout, so you can immediately access them without the need to look them up repeatedly. First, you need to create a class to hold your exact set of views.

Comment: Thanks, I went through the **ViewHolder's** android [official explanation page](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder), it clarified a lot. Even the sample example [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html) gives a good demo.

Answer (score 0):

As Gupta said, you can do the findviewbyid every time you need to populate the row or grid in your case, but that is just inefficient, and thus is better to just do it once, and then store the pointer to every view inside the row or grid (is stored inside the view that represents the row), this will save you time every time you need to inflate a row, and so you will see an increase in performance.

About the documentation, [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29) you have the documentation for the setTag method.
You can see that it says: **"...Tags can also be used to store data within a view without resorting to another data structure."** so there is your answer of why they use that method, and the getTag is just to obtain what you saved before.

Comment: Thanks that clarified a lot(the getTag-setTag methods). But do we not do that with the holder also? I mean every time the getView is called when the list is being loaded for the first time, the holder fetches the ImageView and the TextView.

Comment: Well is not the same, calling the findviewbyid needs to go and find if the view exist inside the parent and if it does exist where it is instantiated, while the holder already has the "pointer" to the view as an object variable, and thus is way faster to access the view from the holder.